# From Android, unable to connect to my Java ServerSocket

Tags: java, android, sockets, connect

I'm a beginner in Java and i want to create a Server on my Desktop PC (running external ip address, verified) and a Client on my Samsung Galaxy S3 with CM11.
On the Server: I've created a ServerSocket on port 6666 (don't ask why) and a while(), whitch contains the Socket ( server = .accept(); ).

On the Client: I've created a Socket client (client = new Socket(HostName, port); ) and i've placed it in a try{}catch(){}: if the connecting fails, the application shows in a TextView "THE SERVER IS DOWN FOR MAINTENANCE".

Error: i can't even connect to my server, but the external ip works with ping  from Terminal Emulator... I don't know why. Is there an error on my client, on my server, or i need to add permission in the Manifest (android)? 
(Android doesn't return any error in the console while the app is running)--

Any idea?
 is why i don't want to show the name of the app.

Server:

```
    package <HIDDEN>;

import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class MainClass {
    public static final String version ="0.1A";
    public static final int port = 6666;
    private static ServerSocket Service;
    private static DataInputStream fromClient;
    private static DataOutputStream toClient;
    private static Socket server;
    static InetAddress Host;

    public static void main(String[] args)  {

        System.out.println("Welcome to <HIDDEN>'s Server! Version ## "+version+" ##");



        try {
            Service = new ServerSocket(port); // INITIALIZE SERVER SOCKET
            System.out.println("Socket created at "+Service.getInetAddress()+"  ");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Error While Creating ServerSocket ' Service ' !!!\n");
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

        while(true) {
            try {
            server = Service.accept();
            System.out.println("Opened Socket on ");
            if(server != null ) {System.out.println("ACCEPTING CONNECTION!");}
            fromClient = new DataInputStream(server.getInputStream());              //  INITIALIZE AND ACCEPT   SOCKET
            toClient = new DataOutputStream(server.getOutputStream());              //  CONNECTION  AND STREAMS

            toClient.writeBoolean(com.<HIDDEN>.FileLoader.verifyLogger(String.valueOf(fromClient.readChar())));

            } catch(IOException e) {
                System.err.println("Error While Initializing A Dialog With Client! "+ "\033FATAL ERROR\033");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Client: [ONLY THE JAVA FILE]

```
package <HIDDEN>;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutput;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;


public class login_activity extends Activity {
    public static String username, password;
    public static final String HostName = "84.227.165.225";
    public static final int port = 6666;
    private Socket client;
    private DataOutputStream toServer;
    private DataInputStream fromServer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { /*ONCREATE VOID*/
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    }


    public void Login(View view) {
        EditText username_et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username_et); // EditTexts
        EditText password_et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password_et); //---
        TextView instructions_tw = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.instructions_tw);
        password = password_et.getText().toString();
        username = username_et.getText().toString();
        try {
            client = new Socket(HostName, port); //INITIALIZE SOCKET
            System.out.print("Initialized Socket, connecting to Server "+HostName+":"+port+"\n");
            toServer = new DataOutputStream(client.getOutputStream()); //System.out.print doesn't works on android...
        }catch (Exception UnkownHostException) {
            instructions_tw.setText("Please Log In Or Register To <NOPE, LOL>\n\n!! THE SERVER IS DOWN FOR MAINTENANCE");
        }

        try {
            toServer.writeBytes(username+"???"+password);
            fromServer = new DataInputStream(client.getInputStream());
            boolean accepted = false;
            if(fromServer.readBoolean()) {
                Intent i = new Intent(this, mainmenu_activity.class);
                startService(i);
            } else {instructions_tw.setText("Please Log In Or Register To <HIDDEN>\n\n!! UNCORRECT PASSWORD OR USERNAME");}
/* THE CODE IS NEVER GOING TO THIS WAY ;( */
        }catch(Exception UnkownHostException){

        }


    }
}
```

***Thanks for help***

Comment: Sorry for my HORROR-English .

Comment: where are you calling `Login` in your activity?

Comment: Login is the MAIN activity

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need to add the `INTERNET` permission to your manifest file to be able to use network sockets from android.

Android documentation says:

> INTERNET  Allows applications to open network sockets.

You should add something like this to your manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

ADDED - Also be sure that server is accessible from Android device: both server and device should be in the same network (wifi connection) or server should be accessible from internet.

Comment: Thanks, it works, :)! Sorry, but i have no reputation, i can't vote up your answer ;(

Comment: That's OK. but you can accept the answer as the correct one.